# when i run this flask code then nothing happens, value doesn't stored in mongodb database

Tags: python, mongodb

Here is my database code in flask and mongodb `snadb.py`

```
 from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for,request
 from bson import ObjectId
 from pymongo import MongoClient
 import os

 app = Flask(__name__)

 client = MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017") #host uri
 db = client.Student #Select the database
 todos = db.Student_list #Select the collection name


 def redirect_url():  
     return url_for('action') 

 @app.route("/list")  
 def lists ():  
   return render_template('snap17.html') 


@app.route("/snap17", methods=['GET','POST'])  
def action ():  
  #Adding a Task  
  name=request.values.get("firstname")  
  todos.insert({ "name":name})  
  return redirect("/list") 

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`

Comment: Can you please provide your template `snap17.html` file your view function do not render any databse data.

Answer (score 0):

In your view function for `/list`. Read your `datas` from databse and accordingly render it in your template like below:

```
@app.route("/list")  
def lists(): 
    todolist = db.Student_list.find()
    return render_template('snap17.html', todolist=todolist)
```

And In your template `snap17.html` render it as

```
<html>
  {% for elem in todolist %}
     <li> {{elem['name']}}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</html>
```

And to write into your database make a `GET` request like this in your existing apllication:

[http://localhost:5000/snap17?firstname="JaiSambhu"](http://localhost:5000/snap17?firstname=JaiSambhu)